# npm not allowing me to update React

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I've not been able to move past `npm audit fix --force`.

How can I fix this problem?

I would like to upgrade to the latest react.

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.1.8",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
    "react-update": "^0.4.4",
    "react-version": "^0.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "use-light-switch": "^1.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject",
    "_start": "react-scripts start",
    "_build": "react-scripts build",
    "_test": "react-scripts test",
    "_eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.12.0",
    "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.8"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "^2.3.2"
  }
}
```

After running `npm audit fix`:

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ini
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/minimist
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rc/node_modules/minimist
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar
npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents
npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/mkdirp
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
npm WARN audit Updating react-scripts to 4.0.3,which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN audit No fix available for react-version@*
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'

added 552 packages, removed 818 packages, changed 339 packages, and audited 1948 packages in 32s

133 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

# npm audit report

node-fetch  <=2.6.0 || 3.0.0-beta.1 - 3.0.0-beta.8
Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1556
No fix available
node_modules/node-fetch
  isomorphic-fetch  2.0.0 - 2.2.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of node-fetch
  node_modules/isomorphic-fetch
    fbjs  0.7.0 - 1.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of isomorphic-fetch
    node_modules/fbjs
      react  0.15.0-alpha.1 - 16.4.2
      Depends on vulnerable versions of fbjs
      node_modules/react-version/node_modules/react
        react-version  *
        Depends on vulnerable versions of react
        node_modules/react-version

postcss  7.0.0 - 8.2.9
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1693
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@2.1.8, which is a breaking change
node_modules/postcss
node_modules/resolve-url-loader/node_modules/postcss
  autoprefixer  9.0.0 - 9.8.6
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/autoprefixer
  css-blank-pseudo  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-blank-pseudo
    postcss-preset-env  >=6.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-blank-pseudo
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-prefers-color-scheme
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-color-gray
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-double-position-gradients
    node_modules/postcss-preset-env
  css-declaration-sorter  4.0.0 - 5.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-declaration-sorter
  css-has-pseudo  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-has-pseudo
  css-loader  2.0.0 - 4.3.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-loader
    react-scripts  >=2.0.0-next.03604a46
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
    node_modules/react-scripts
  css-prefers-color-scheme  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-prefers-color-scheme
  cssnano  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.1.1 - 4.1.11
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/cssnano
    optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin  3.2.1 || >=5.0.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano
    node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
  cssnano-preset-default  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano-util-raw-cache
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-calc
  node_modules/cssnano-preset-default
  cssnano-util-raw-cache  >=4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/cssnano-util-raw-cache
  icss-utils  4.0.0 - 4.1.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/icss-utils
    postcss-modules-local-by-default  2.0.0 - 4.0.0-rc.4
    Depends on vulnerable versions of icss-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
    node_modules/postcss-modules-local-by-default
    postcss-modules-values  2.0.0 - 4.0.0-rc.5
    Depends on vulnerable versions of icss-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
    node_modules/postcss-modules-values
  postcss-attribute-case-insensitive  4.0.0 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-attribute-case-insensitive
  postcss-browser-comments  2.0.0 - 3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-browser-comments
    postcss-normalize  7.0.0 - 9.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-browser-comments
    node_modules/postcss-normalize
  postcss-calc  6.0.2 - 7.0.5
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-calc
  postcss-color-functional-notation  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-functional-notation
  postcss-color-gray  >=5.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-gray
  postcss-color-hex-alpha  4.0.0 - 6.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-hex-alpha
  postcss-color-mod-function  >=3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-mod-function
  postcss-color-rebeccapurple  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-rebeccapurple
  postcss-colormin  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-colormin
  postcss-convert-values  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-convert-values
  postcss-custom-media  7.0.0 - 7.0.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-custom-media
  postcss-custom-properties  8.0.0 - 10.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-custom-properties
  postcss-custom-selectors  5.0.0 - 5.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-custom-selectors
  postcss-dir-pseudo-class  >=5.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-dir-pseudo-class
  postcss-discard-comments  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-comments
  postcss-discard-duplicates  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-duplicates
  postcss-discard-empty  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-empty
  postcss-discard-overridden  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-overridden
  postcss-double-position-gradients  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-double-position-gradients
  postcss-env-function  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-env-function
  postcss-flexbugs-fixes  4.0.0 - 4.2.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-flexbugs-fixes
  postcss-focus-visible  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-focus-visible
  postcss-focus-within  >=3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-focus-within
  postcss-font-variant  4.0.0 - 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-font-variant
  postcss-gap-properties  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-gap-properties
  postcss-image-set-function  >=3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-image-set-function
  postcss-initial  3.0.0 - 3.0.4
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-initial
  postcss-lab-function  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-lab-function
  postcss-loader  3.0.0 - 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-loader
  postcss-logical  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-logical
  postcss-media-minmax  4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-media-minmax
  postcss-merge-longhand  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.6 - 4.0.11
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-merge-longhand
  postcss-merge-rules  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-merge-rules
  postcss-minify-font-values  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-font-values
  postcss-minify-gradients  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-gradients
  postcss-minify-params  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-params
  postcss-minify-selectors  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-selectors
  postcss-modules-extract-imports  2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-modules-extract-imports
  postcss-modules-scope  2.0.0 - 2.2.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-modules-scope
  postcss-nesting  7.0.0 - 7.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-nesting
  postcss-normalize-charset  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-charset
  postcss-normalize-display-values  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-display-values
  postcss-normalize-positions  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-positions
  postcss-normalize-repeat-style  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-repeat-style
  postcss-normalize-string  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-string
  postcss-normalize-timing-functions  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-timing-functions
  postcss-normalize-unicode  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-unicode
  postcss-normalize-url  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-url
  postcss-normalize-whitespace  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-whitespace
  postcss-ordered-values  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.1.1 - 4.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-ordered-values
  postcss-overflow-shorthand  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-overflow-shorthand
  postcss-page-break  2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-page-break
  postcss-place  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-place
  postcss-pseudo-class-any-link  >=6.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-pseudo-class-any-link
  postcss-reduce-initial  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-reduce-initial
  postcss-reduce-transforms  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-reduce-transforms
  postcss-replace-overflow-wrap  3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-replace-overflow-wrap
  postcss-selector-matches  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-selector-matches
  postcss-selector-not  4.0.0 - 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-selector-not
  postcss-svgo  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-svgo
  postcss-unique-selectors  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-unique-selectors
  resolve-url-loader  >=3.0.0-alpha.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/resolve-url-loader
  stylehacks  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/stylehacks

85 vulnerabilities (5 low, 80 moderate)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

---

Deleted `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, after `npm i --force`:

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm WARN   7 more (@testing-library/react, react-dom, styled-components, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8" from use-light-switch@1.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/use-light-switch
npm WARN   use-light-switch@"^1.0.1" from the root project
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
```

---

After `yarn install` and `yarn upgrade`:

```
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
warning react-scripts > babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning react-scripts > resolve-url-loader > rework > css > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning react-scripts > resolve-url-loader > rework > css > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning react-scripts > resolve-url-loader > rework > css > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/topo > @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
warning react-scripts > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > strip-comments > babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread > babel-runtime > core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
warning react-scripts > jest > jest-cli > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning react-scripts > jest > jest-cli > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning react-scripts > jest > jest-cli > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > request > har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
warning react-version > react > fbjs > core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > @babel/eslint-parser@7.13.14" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.11.0".
warning " > @babel/eslint-parser@7.13.14" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@>=7.5.0".
warning " > @testing-library/user-event@13.1.8" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
warning " > styled-components@5.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-is@>= 16.8.0".
warning " > use-light-switch@1.0.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8".
[4/4]   Rebuilding all packages...
```

Comment: can you check if the NPM is upto date ?

Comment: @kunalpanchal It's at `7.12.1`

Comment: just delete first your node modules then just npm i

Comment: try to delete all your node_modules and re-install them

Comment: Done that. Posted an update to the question. Same errors.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to do this?

```
[sudo] npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli 

npm cache verify 

[sudo] npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: I'm using React?

Answer (score 0):

It may cause by conflicts of versions of the dependencies of the packages.

To install yarn and use yarn install may solve the issue

Comment: I tried yarn. Posted the output as an update to the question please take a look. Still getting errors.

Comment: I see all are the warnings. Is there any error messages displayed?   Can you try: rm -rf node_modules/
npm cache clean  yarn